# Mongodb Sum field within date range and other filters

Tags: mongodb

Assuming I have the following document structure in my mongodb:

```
{
  _id: "tMSfNq9JR85XDaQe5"
  customerid: "QDGvBQhS6vYgZtnRr"
  employeeid: "QDGvBQhS6vYgZtnRr" 
  date: Sun Dec 07 2014 19:50:21 GMT+0800 (HKT) 
  projectid: "S83NEGHnrefvfASrf" 
  hours: 2
}
```

Is it possible to get total hours spent on a specific project and customer, grouped by employee and date, while querying data within specific date range, so that the output will be for example like:

```
{ "projectid":"XXX", "date":"Dec 1, 2014", "employeeid":"AAA", "totalHrs":"20" }
{ "projectid":"XXX", "date":"Dec 1, 2014", "employeeid":"BBB", "totalHrs":"11" }
{ "projectid":"XXX", "date":"Dec 2, 2014", "employeeid":"AAA", "totalHrs":"3" }
{ "projectid":"XXX", "date":"Dec 2, 2014", "employeeid":"BBB", "totalHrs":"5" }
{ "projectid":"XXX", "date":"Dec 2, 2014", "employeeid":"CCC", "totalHrs":"18" }
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post your sample data?

Comment: @yogesh that's what inside the document structure posted above, this is a real copy of one of my documents data

Comment: That does not look like an ISODate() so querying them will be complicated. Any chance you can change the type?

Comment: @Martin yes I can change to ISODate. Thanks

Comment: For this type of query it could be worth to have a look at the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) provided by MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Hi as per my understand I think you want to groups on projectid and employeeid as looking to your desired output so I think below aggregation may work in this case

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
                       {"$group":{"_id":{"projectId":"$projectid","employeeId":"$employeeid","date":"$date"},
                       "totalHrs":{"$sum":"$hours"}}},
                      {"$project":{"projectid":"$_id.projectId",
                         "date":"$_id.date","employeeid":"$_id.employeeId",
                        "totalHrs":"$totalHrs",
                          "_id":0}}
                        )
```

Comment: You could further improve your answer, by formatting the `date` properly as in the expected output.

Comment: You may also want to use [date operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) in the group to collect results by day. Grouping just by `date` will separate documents from the same day with different times.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to group by projectid,date,employeeid**

```
db.collectionname.aggregate({"$project":{"projectid":1,"date":1,"employeeid":1,"totalHrs":1}},
{"$group":{"_id":{"$projectId":"$projectid","date":"$date","employeeId":"$employeeid"}, 
"totalHrs":{"$sum":"$hours"}}})
```